# Captain, there's a riddle for yar!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Captain, I am willing to bet,

That yar will never get,

The meaning of this riddle!

---

Many siblings live together,

Sister and brother equal in number,

Many many pets but not a fiddle!

---

Sometimes they're at war.

And sometimes they swindle yar,

But they truly amaze a kiddle!

Comment: Left and right hand fingers? Two teams in a football game? A group of siblings looking in a mirror?

Comment: is the misspelling of "captain" intentional?

Comment: No. I can't type apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is:

> A deck of cards (as Brent Hackers sort of points out in his answer and the comment from OP)

**Reasoning:**

Captain, I am willing to bet,
That yar will never get,
The meaning of this riddle!

> You bet on card games specifically the various forms of poker.

Many siblings live together,

> Referring to the Jack Queen King I believe

Sister and brother equal in number,

> There are 4 Queens and 4 Kings which I believe are the siblings

Many many pets but not a fiddle!

> No Idea, maybe the number cards are the pets

Sometimes they're at war.

> Refers to the card game war

And sometimes they swindle yar,

> Sometimes people cheat in betting card games

But they truly amaze a kiddle!

> A deck of cards is used in a lot of magic tricks that will amaze children (and adults alike)

Comment: You got it! Nice catch in the first line. I never even intended that connection! The second to last line isn't about people cheating. That one is about how cards just cause people to gamble away their money. So the /cards/ swindle yar. Did you see the connection about the fiddle?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck no, I don't really get the fiddle part

Comment: You were right about what the pets are. Which pet is notably missing?

Comment: Huh.  Cards would have been my answer as well - but since when are "kings" and "queens" siblings?  If anything, they're spouses.  The sister of a King is never Queen unless the King dies first.  Likewise, the brother of a Queen wouldn't be King unless the Queen died first.

Comment: The queens are all sisters. The kings are all brothers. After all, they rule different kingdoms.

Answer (score 2):

Probably miles off

> A pair of Dice?
>  same numbers on each
>  don't know about 'pets'...
>  war = board games etc?
>  you can loose a lot of money playing with them
>  and kids like them because games...

:/

> Alternatively, maybe a roulette table or a deck of cards (black and red in equal number), both can involve a 'bet' and the above applies.

Comment: One of them is right. Think about the theme of the riddle...

Comment: That was a good one.  Kicking myself now.  Is the 'but not a fiddle' thing somehow cat related?  I'm still scratching my head at that bit.

Comment: The fiddle has a certain shape of a notably missing "pet".

Comment: The fiddle is the number "1". It has a similar shape.